# How to add footnotes in htlatex via fn-in?

Tags: errors, footnotes, conversion, tex4ht, htlatex

In the html code that is generated by htlatex I  want to have footnotes appear on the same page instead of a new one (just like in the .pdf that is generated by pdflatex). So I read about the `fn-in` option that I should pass to htlatex. Now I am absolutely clueless about how to do this. If I type

```
htlatex main.tex "-fn-in"
```

(or just `"fn_in"` htlatex complains:

```
! I can't find file `-fn-in.cfg'.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.12 \begin{document}

Please type another input file name:
```

So what am I supposed to do instead?

Answer (score 7):

First option in `htlatex`'s second parameter must be either name of custom config file, `html` or `xhtml`. Default is `html`, which is used if you omit the parameter. Correct option for inline footnotes is `fn-in`. So your command line call should be:

```
htlatex main.tex "xhtml,fn-in"
```